# MDADM - Degrading when copying files to share

Tags: installation, server, partitioning, raid, mdadm

We have a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server which is configured with a 2 disk software 1 RAID (mdadm).  The disks are 3TB and partitioned with a 1MB GPT partition and with the remaining assigned to the RAID.  The RAID partition is then allocated as LVM Volume Group and hosts three logical partition for the /boot, /, swap.  Following the system being built we tested it by removing a disk and all worked well.  We then replaced the disk and re-add the disk back into the RAID.

We have now installed SAMBA on the system and are trying to copy 200Gb of data to a subfolder of the root partition.  Every time we do this the RAID degrades and one of the partitions sda2 or sdb2 drops off (removedO).

I can't see any errors in the logs as to the cause for this. Recommendations or suggestions as to where we may find the cause would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your `dmesg` log tell you around that time? I've seen hard drives becoming unresponsive for a few seconds during the  time being used heavily for a longer time which may cause mdadm to kick the drive. Also post the SMART output for your drives. e.g. `smartctl -A /dev/sda`

Answer (score 0):

You can run some tests with smartctl, dd and so on.

1. smartctl --test=long /dev/sda (and sdb)
2. dd if=/dev/urandom of=test.file bs=64K count=1000 (for example)

I think it is hdd or hdd controller problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure it's a disk issue although I've tried two 3TB disks (ST3000NC000) which were both new.